# Presentation of the Monster Group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I was reading about the monster group, and how hard it was to do calculations in it, and I wondered: Is there a known presentation of the monster group? I know that it is a hurwitz group, but other than that I don't know. If we have two generators a and b such that $a^2=b^3=(ab)^7=1$, what are the possible orders of $[a,b]$? I believe that the conjugacy classes are known, so if you are given the conjugacy classes of two elements x and y, can we determine the possible conjugacy classes of $xy$?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a 12-generator 80-relator presentation for the Monster group. Specifically, we have 78 relators for the Coxeter group Y443:

- $12$ relators of the form $x^2 = 1$, one for each node in the Coxeter-Dynkin diagram;
- $11$ relators of the form $(xy)^3 = 1$, one for each pair of adjacent nodes;
- $55$ relators of the form $(xy)^2 = 1$ (commutators), one for each pair of non-adjacent nodes;

together with a single 'spider' relator, $(a b_1 c_1 a b_2 c_2 a b_3 c_3)^{10} = 1$, which results in the group $M \times C_2$. We can get rid of the $C_2$ by quotienting out by an eightieth relation, $x = 1$, where $x$ is the unique non-identity element in the centre of the group.

See http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~jnb/web/Pres/Mnst.html for the explicit Coxeter-Dynkin diagram.

Comment: So, it is x^2=1 for each node, (xy)^3 for each pair of adjacent nodes, and [x,y]^2 ([x,y] is the commutator of x and y) for each pair of non-adjacent nodes. Then the "spider" relation, and quotienting out the center. Wow, that is very interesting.

Comment: Also, what is the center element? It doesn't say on the page.

Comment: What would happen if you did not include the spider relation?

Comment: without the spider, you get some weird infinite Coxeter group.

Comment: Your first comment is correct, except that the relators corresponding to non-adjacent nodes are $[x,y] = 1$ (i.e. $x$ and $y$ commute), which is equivalent to $(xy)^2 = 1$ since $x$ and $y$ are elements of order 2 (Coxeter groups are generated by reflections).

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Are all coxeter groups represented with diagrams like this. Also, how did anyone find the spider relation in the first place?

Comment: Yes, Coxeter groups are presented by Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams, where each vertex corresponds to a reflection and each pair of points corresponds to a relation $(xy)^n = 1$. When $n = 2$ we omit the edge, when $n = 3$ we draw an unlabelled edge, and otherwise we label the edge with the value of $n$. Some Coxeter groups are infinitely-generated, thus don't correspond to finite diagrams.

Comment: Interesting. What about the spider relation? How was that found? Were they intentionally trying to find the monster group, or was it an accident?

Comment: I'm not sure how the spider relation was discovered, but it certainly stems from a conjecture by John Conway (circa 1980, proved by Ivanov and Norton in 1990) that Y555 quotiented by the spider gives the Bimonster group. This prompted investigation of other Ypqr groups, summarised in a later paper by Ivanov: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869399978821
If the spider relation seems too arbitrary, there is an alternative formulation where the diagram is the 26-vertex incidence graph of the projective plane over F3, and the relations correspond to 'deflating' free 12-gons.

Answer (score 7):

A presentation for $M$ was [constructed](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/chapter.jsf?bid=CBO9780511629259&cid=CBO9780511629259A013) by A.A.Ivanov. This presentation is not so easy to describe; it arises from an amalgam of parabolics in certain diagram geometry. S.Norton then proved that the Y-presentation from ATLAS indeed describes the "Bimonster" (see Derek Holt's comment to the previous answer).

Comment: I never would have thought it would be the wreath product of the monster by Z2. The link you gave me does not let me see where the monster group is derived, let alone the whole chapter. Could someone email me a copy?

Comment: sure, but where to? your profile doesn't reveal any email...

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11004520/CBO9780511629259A013.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Bimonster can be presented by the Coxeter group of the 26-node graph of the projective plane of order 3:  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.23.2634 (26 Implies The Bimonster, by John H. Conway and Christopher S. Simons). See also http://citeseer.uark.edu:8080/citeseerx/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=57D5F004B2D42A5AE3CF28FD1C29E8E7?doi=10.1.1.137.1363 (An Elementary Approach to the Monster, by Christopher S. Simons).